# Adding data to the table with the checkbox checked using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add another column to the table header has a `checkbox`? When I add an item to the table the row will be added with checkbox column with checked ...

[jsfiddle.net/e254w/34](http://jsfiddle.net/e254w/34)

Krish

Comment: Post a small, self-contained example code here to illustrate the problem -- a Fiddle is great, but not sufficient on its own. Answers on this site are intended to have historical lookup & archive value, which your question (since it has no detail) does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding input tag like this.

```
$("<tr><td><input type='checkbox' checked/></td></tr>")
```

Working DEMO - http://jsfiddle.net/e254w/36/

Answer (score 0):

You can use .after() to place a new TH with a checkbox after the last TH:

```
$('#datatable th:last').after('<th><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></th>');
```

Also, don't forget to add a TD to all the other rows or else you will have alignment issues:

```
$('#datatable td:last').after('<td></td>');
```

UPDATE:

```
$('#datatable tr:last').after('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
```

If you just need a column and not the entire row then this will work:

```
$('#datatable th:first').before('<th><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></th>');
```

Comment: I wanted to add as a first column in the header and in the data row..i mean td

Comment: I think I was confused by your question. I have updated my post.

Comment: My checkbox should be the first column in the table..Do you have the working jsfiddle??